# Can't call .save() after using aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have to use aggregate to find a user ID inside an array of objects, and once I have it I want to update a document with that ID. But when I try to call .save() like I would have after for example using `Product.findById(productId)`, I get an error which only occurs when I use aggregation.

> product.save is not a function

```
exports.putGift = (req, res, next) => {
  const productId = req.body.productId;
  const requestId = req.body.requestId;
  Product.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(productId) } },
    { $unwind: "$requests" },
    { $match: { "requests._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(requestId) } },
    { $project: { "requests.userId": 1 } }
  ])
    .then(product => {
      const userId = product[0].requests.userId;
      product.winner = userId;
      product.status = "given";
      return product.save()
      .then(result => {
        console.log("success");
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: Yes, you can't call '.save()' after aggregate. Aggregate is like using lean(), it doesn't return mongoose document.

Comment: @Visrozar, thanks for the comment. Then how do I update the record if I can't call .save()

Comment: You'll need to write a separate update query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant use `.save` in aggregate. You would need to use [.update()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) method to update the document.

Use it like:

```
Product.update({_id: 'someid'}, { $set: { winner: 'somevalue', status: 'somevalue' } });
```